# Image validation doesn't work in Laravel Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, voyager

I have used validation for image in Laravel Voyager BREAD. But it doesn't work. It takes all dimension of images.

Here is my code

```
{
"validation": {
    "rule": "dimensions:width=100,height=100",
    "messages": {
        "dimensions": "This :attribute field is a must."
    }
}
}
```

Image for more clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the docs you need to add [mimes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimes) rule, and use [dimensions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-dimensions) rule like:

```
'rule' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|dimensions:width=340,height=960'
```

Comment: @raff what is the extension of uploaded image ?

Comment: see the rule! `mimes:jpeg,bmp,png` means that `png` format is **allowed!** if you don't want to let the users to upload `png` then remove it from the rule definition `mimes:jpeg,bmp`

Comment: all yours... I actually need the validation of dimension. I want to upload only `960px * 340px` size image....you understand brother ?

Comment: No error. Just uplaoded. I have uploaded below or higher dimension from '960px * 340px'....But it still successfully uploaded to database. No error given

Comment: @raff may You provide the rules that you have written ?

Comment: Sure ! Here `"rule": "mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|dimensions:width=960,height=340",`

Comment: visit the link https://mattstauffer.com/blog/image-dimension-validation-rules-in-laravel-5-3/

Comment: ha ha... I visit that first... didn't get the result. That's why I asked here. It's ok my friend. Thanks for your trying

Comment: Good luck then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a creating a rule since this requires several arguments

```
 use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

    Validator::make($data, [
        'image' => [
            'required',
            Rule::dimensions()->maxWidth(1000)->maxHeight(500)->ratio(3 / 2),
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: I am using Laravel Voyager admin panel. There are some validation specific rules. You have got the idea from [https://voyager.readme.io/docs]